# How to fetch all data from order table, but some data from order item table in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two table Order and Order Items, and one order have many order items with multiple status like 'New', 'Cancelled', 'Delivered'.

So when I fetch all orders which contains order items that only have status='New', then it returns all the order items that have status other than 'New' like 'Cancelled', 'Delivered'.

So basically, it returns all the order items with particular order-id, it does not return partial order items against that order-id.

Here is my code:

**Views.py**

```
order = Order.objects.distinct().filter(orderitem__status=request.data['status'])
serializer = ListOrderSerializer(order, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class ListOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
order_items = ListOrderItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Order
    exclude = ('id',)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to filter a related field in DRF, but pretty much all of them involve overriding the corresponding serializer field. What you could try is:

- **Solution 1:** create a customer order property (e.g. `delivered_items`) that returns filtered results and pass it to the serializer field using the `OrderItemSerializer(source="delivered_items", many=True)`
- **Solution 2:** override ListOrderSerializer `to_representation` method to exclude some results. I think that the status would be typically passed in request GET as `request.query_params["status"]`. You could pass that to the serializer context (override `get_serializer_context`) and access `self.context` in `to_representation`.

Comment: Can you provide complete solution to this with code.

Comment: I tried with the second one, but not working. Please provide me actual code.